# Class path resource can not be opened

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I am trying to load a file name `SpringConfig.xml` from directory

`resources\cfg\SpringConfig.xml` using the

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/cfg/SpringConfig.xml")
```

which does not work, but the same thing if I change the location as `resources\SpringConfig.xml` it does work fine with

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringConfig.xml")
```

but I want to use the prior one, can someone help on how I fix this?

Comment: Did you try without the leading backslash: `cfg\SpringConfig.xml` ? Also note that in Java strings you'd need to escape backslashes, e.g. `"cfg\\SpringConfig.xml"`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `/` instead of `\` in your Strings.

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes are special in Java. Try switching to forward slashes. (In fact, it shouldn't even compile with the backslashes in your example!)

Similarly, the initial slash should probably be omitted, as otherwise you're specifying an absolute rather than a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("cfg/SpringConfig.xml")
```